# How to understand and implement the Twitter API to make an Android Twitter client

Tags: java, android, api, twitter

So far, I have succeeded to authenticate my app. Now I want to know how to implement the codes to pull and display statuses, mentions, messages and etc.  I am using the twitter4j library. Can somebody post a snippet of an activity that pulls and display timeline in a listview? Please dont link me to the twitter dev page or any example library, I just want somebody to post an EXAMPLE. By doing this, Im going to understand how the API works.
Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are loads and loads of different examples. Just search for the different parts you want.

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/108.html
marakana has several parts. [Part 1](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/67.html), [Part 2](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/69.html), [Part 3](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/72.html), [Part 4](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/73.html)

Another example: http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/11/21/twitter-client-for-android-how-to-make-xml-over-http-calls/

Comment: I have opened those site before, some methods are deprecated. I need something up-to-date.